# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' pytthon:convert str list to int list

Tags: python-3.x, list, type-conversion

code:-

```
team_O = [int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]
```

working:-
input in one line is 1 2 3 4 5 6
it split by space ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
and convert each element str list to int list

expected output:-

```
team_O =[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

error:-

```
File "CandidateCode.py", line 9, in <listcomp>
    team_G = [int(j) for j in input().split(" ")]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your usage of str.split(). You pass it an explicit separator,

```
>>> '1 2 3 4'.split(' ')
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

While this looks like what you want, it is not in most cases. For example, if two words are separated by two consecutive occurences of `separator`, the empty space between those is part of the output,

```
>>> '1 2 3  4'.split(' ').
['1', '2', '3', '', '4']
```

Likewise, leading and trailing spaces have a similar effect,

```
>>> '1 2 3 4 '.split(' ')
['1', '2', '3', '4', '']
```

The [str.split Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) states that,

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is
>   applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, (...)

Long story short: don't pass a separator,

```
>>> '1 2 3 4'.split()
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> '1 2 3  4'.split()
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> '1 2 3 4 '.split()
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `split()` can be used to remove whitespace, so you can use:

```
team_0=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
```